# Unable to connect nodejs to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I just created a `mongo` database on `DigitalOcean` following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04 and everything works fine when I'm accessing a database from the `mongo shell` but I can't connect to the database using `node.js`

This is my code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@droplet_ip:27017/my_database', (err, res) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log('connected');
  }
})
```

And this is the error:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [droplet_ip:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to droplet_ip:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:192:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:197:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:342:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [droplet_ip:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to droplet_ip:27017 timed out]' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might not **enabled** the `mongo port` to access from `Remote` location .

First run the following commands on your `droplet`

> sudo ufw enable
>
> sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
>
> sudo ufw allow 27017

Now open the **mongo config** file and add append your `droplet ip` in `bindIp` section.

file path:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

Add the below code, edit `droplet_ip` with your **server ip** :

```
 . . .
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, droplet_ip
 . . .
```

Now restart `mongo` by below command:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

Comment: Ok, Run this command in your droplet. "sudo ufw allow 27017".